# Mechanize to access live.com email returns no forms on the login page

Tags: ruby, mechanize

Here's my code:

```
    mech = Mechanize.new { |agent|
    agent.follow_meta_refresh = true
    }
    mech.get("https://mail.live.com") do |login_page|
        puts login_page.forms
    end
```

The problem is, login_page.forms always comes back as nil. If I run the command in irb I just get back []. Is there a better way to find and fill out the login form? Is it even possible to access live.com email via mechanize?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Mechanize doesn't work with Java script.